# iAd interstitial ads crashing with error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I have code for my interstitial ads in my GameScene, and every time they're supposed to be called, I get the error in the title with this line:

```
func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    iAdInterstitialView = SKView()
   iAdInterstitialView.frame = self.view!.bounds //This line
view?.addSubview(iAdInterstitialView)

   interstitialAd.presentInView(iAdInterstitialView)
UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
}
```

Has anyone else had this problem and  fixed it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that unwrapped value is `nil` in your `self.view!`. 
You can check it this way:

```
if let view = self.view {
    iAdInterstitialView.frame = view.bounds
}
```

Comment: Its showing the ad now, but its also making my screen black out like a second after its displayed.

Comment: Here is a short example how to use Interstitial iAds https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16062 . Try to use `UIView` instead of `SKView`.